# Jquery Cursor in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Heres the demo http://www.ningbomedia.com/global_admin/test.php#

Once I have selected any of the top navigations my cursor turns into an arrow, then when I mouse out and mouse in again it will return to a hand.

I want it to always be a hand when its over the navigation.

This problem only seems to be happening In Google Chrome.

I am new to Jquery so any other comments on my code would be appreciated!

Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swung by your demo page in chrome and was able to reproduce the issue. I was able to narrow down the cause to the href being `#` which kinda behaved like a refresh. When I removed `href="#"` making the tags Dashboard it worked exactly the way you want it to.

I'm not sure if this approach is valid markup so you may want to use list items instead (`<li></li>` of anchor tags `<a></a>`) This is how I generally code my navs.

Comment: apparently this is legal. According to W3C `Authors may also create an A element that specifies no anchors, i.e., that doesn't specify href, name, or id. Values for these attributes may be set at a later time through scripts.`

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for you help, that was driving me crazy!

Comment: I'm not sure if every browser will put that cursor there with no href attribute. If you have further difficulties, look into href="javascript:void(0)"

Answer (score 1):

No need for JQuery. In your CSS, just set `cursor:pointer;` to the `#navarea`. Works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: I have the css cursor:pointer on the nav area and all the other divs but for me in Chrome on a mac, the pointer turns into default as soon as I select an item from the navigation.

Comment: This didn't work for me in chrome 15.0 on mac osx snow leopard.

Comment: thanks @magicmike its not working for me either, any workaround ideas?

Comment: Sorry for being redundant, I didn't see your comment here. I was able to make it work with both anchor tags (without a href) and list item tags (making your menu and sub-menues out of nested unordered lists.